# Determine layer visibility with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend

From some other posts I found that i can determine a layers visiblity by something like

```
#assume lyr_name the layers name to determine visibity for
l = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]
vis = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(l.id()).isVisible()
```

Apart from this being put in a method like

```
def isVis(lyr_name):
    l = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_name)[0]
    return QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(l.id()).isVisible()
```

Is this the recommendend way to check if a layer is visible, whichs name is known or is there a more simpler approach?

Comment: Could you please provide some context as to what you are trying to achieve? :)

Answer (score 3):

You are right. That's the way to check the layer visibility in QGIS 3.x, provided by [QgsLayerTreeNode](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html).

You can make it more easy to read, if you assign variables, like:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
root.findLayer(layer.id()).isVisible();
```

There are other methods related to visibility in `QgsLayerTreeNode`. This `isVisible()` also checks if some group above is unchecked.

In the following case, the `isVisible()` applied to **House numbers** layer will be false, although the layer is checked.

[image]